# Guardar Cambios Git stash

Tags: git

¿Porque cuando creo un stash en git para guardar mis cambios se crea, pero aun me sigue marcando cambios y con esto no me puedo cambiar de rama, hasta crear otro y limpiar la rama?

Comment: ¿Qué comandos usas en concreto?

Comment: git stash save -u <nombre del stash>

Comment: @abulafia git stash save -u <nombre del stash>

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con la documentación de [git stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), el comando `save` está obsoleto, pero en todo caso es sinónimo de `push`. Y si te fijas en la documentación, `git stash push` espera el nombre de una *ruta* (es decir, un fichero o una carpeta) y no el nombre de un stash.

Por tanto si estás poniendo algo como:

```
git stash save -u mi_stash
```

se creará un *stash* sin nombre (pero con un hash para que te puedas referir a él), y se meterá en el stash todos los contenidos de la carpeta `mi_stash`, que probablemente no existe, lo que explica que no se te guarde nada.

Prueba a poner simplemente `git stash push -u` sin más argumentos. La opción `-u` por cierto es para que también guarde los archivos *untracked* (es decir, que no estén bajo control de versiones). No veo necesario en princpio hacer eso, pues esos archivos normalmente no los va a tocar `git` de todas formas cuando hagas un *checkout*.

Comment: Gracias @abulafia probare el comando